# Potentially Inefficient For Loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I noticed the below and think it is inefficient. What am I missing? I imagine there must be speed advantages I am unaware of. For context, this is production code in a brokerage firm's API.

What I saw:

```
const unsigned MAX_ATTEMPTS = 50;
unsigned attempt = 0;

for (;;) {
    ++attempt;
    // logic, functions, output
    if( attempt >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
        break;
    }
}
```

What I expected:

```
const unsigned MAX_ATTEMPTS = 50;
for(unsigned attempt = 0; attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS; ++attempt){
    // logic, functions, output
}
```

*** Corrected typo

Comment: They have different functionallity (assuming typo in (2)): (1) will do the logic functions unconditional once. (2) will not if the exit condition is true on entry.

Comment: `for(unsigned attempt = 1; attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; ++attempt)` presumably.

Comment: In their code, the body of the loop sees `attempt` ranging from 1 to `MAX_ATTEMPTS`. In yours, it sees 0 to `MAX_ATTEMPTS - 1`

Comment: I don't think it's "inefficient", but the difference is that the second form is more conventional and easily understood by humans. I also really doubt that `++attempt` is going to be the performance bottleneck in this code.

Comment: The answer to these types of questions is always the same:  profile, profile, profile.

Comment: In terms of the CPU overhead of the looping constructs themselves, there is no significant efficiency difference between the two forms.  (others have noted that there is a difference in how many times the "logic, functions, output" section might get executed, and a difference in ease-of-readability)

Comment: You should probably also change `<=` to `<`

Comment: But it should still be initialized to 1 to be equivalent :)

Comment: @tadman Why did you remove the C tag? And the two other tags?

Comment: @klutt It's explicitly labelled C++ despite the other tags. I also doubt anyone's pinned "loops" as a tag they're interested in helping out with.

Comment: @tadman Ok, very silly me. Did not read the title.

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed the below and think it is inefficient. What am I missing?

That it's pointless to speculate about efficiency unless you know

0. whether there's a measurable problem
1. how long it currently takes
2. how long it's desirable for it to take
3. how much effort it would cost to improve

So, if this loop is not speed-critical and is dominated by the `logic, functions, output` - which for the avoidance of doubt it *absolutely is* unless they have output orders of magnitude more efficient than anyone else - then there is no problem in the first place, and your speculation is unlikely to be productive.

If this loop is somehow speed critical (I emphasize again how unlikely this is), then *you need to measure it*  - **and** you need to decide what result would be acceptable. Otherwise you're just wasting time rearranging deckchairs instead of doing anything valuable.

Finally, if you pass tests zero through two inclusive, you still need to judge whether any improvement is worth the effort required to implement, test, review and deploy it. If it turns out to be 1% below the optimum latency decided at step 2, and some other part of your codebase is currently burning money, then this still not likely to be top priority.

From a learning rather than a business point of view however - it's great to spot potential inefficiencies like these. That's not because they're important to fix, but because you're probably wrong, and the process of learning how to benchmark them - and of understanding *why* you were wrong - is good experience and will improve your intuition for next time.

Answer (score 3):

The only differences are that in the original code:

- You can access the last value of `attempt` after the loop
- The loop will be executed at least once.

It offers no obvious benefits. And if you ask me, the original code is quite ugly. I would have done this instead:

```
unsigned attempt = 1;
do {
    // Logic
} while(++attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS);
```

There is a chance that one of them gets compiled to faster code. In order to find out, you need to benchmark it. Which one is faster (if any) can vary from system to system.

Comment: About speed or efficiency, it's good to remember that code is usually optimized by the compiler (you can control optimization using necessary flags)

Comment: @user4581301 That's why I initialized to 1 instead of 0

Comment: Whoops. Missed that.,

Comment: `++attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS` solves the last issue you mentioned.

Comment: @KorelK Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cut too much, and I suppose that it was something like this.

```
for (;;) {
    ++attempt;
    // logic, functions, output
    result = somefunc();
    if(result == SUCCESS) break;
    if( attempt >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I do not like zillions breaks in the code. I prefer:

```
do {
    // Logic
    result = somefunc();
} while(result != SUCCESS && attempt++ < MAX_ATTEMPTS);
```

If I am right your version should look like this

```
result = FAILURE;
for(unsigned attempt = 1; result != SUCCESS && attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; ++attempt){
     result = somefunc();
   // logic, functions, output
}
```

There will not be any difference in performance between those versions. It is a question of the personal preferences